# How do I filter values from a many to many relationship?

Tags: postgresql

If i have a many to many relationship between articles and tags, what is the best way to go about selecting all articles that contain tags that a specific user has stored?

For this example, assume there's a users table with a user_id column.
Articles

| Article_id | Article_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dogs |
| 2 | Cats |
| 3 | Sheep |

Tags

| Tag_id |
| --- |
| Pets |
| Outdoors |
| Grass |

Article_Tags

| Article_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pets |
| 1 | Grass |
| 1 | Outdoors |
| 2 | Outdoors |
| 3 | Grass |
| 3 | Outdoors |

Users_Tags

| User_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | Pets |
| User1 | Grass |
| User2 | Pets |

If I wanted to show all articles that has any of the tags that a user has stored associated with their id in Users_Tags, what would be the best way to do so? I mettled with nested selects and inner joins but I couldn't logic out the best way to go about this.

For example, since User1 has the tags Pets and Grass stored with their User_id, I would want to return the articles with the ID of 1 and 2, since both of those articles have at least one of the users' stored tags associated with it.

```
Article_id | Article_ Name |Tag_id
     1     |       Dogs    |  Pets
     1     |       Dogs    |  Grass
     3     |       Sheep   |  Grass
```

A sample output is provided above. I included repeats of the same article for clarities sake, although in reality I would like to only repeat an article a single time.

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for the formatting help! I was having trouble.

Comment: Hi @tagger please provide sample output. This better to understand.

Comment: I have added a sample output @Rahul Biswas

Comment: Hi @tagger why dogs equal to Casts for 1 not grass

Comment: @Rahul Biswas Sorry! I made the edit while half asleep. It should have been equal to grass.

Comment: thanks. I'm waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, it should be ordinal structure with "inner join". Seemingly, the column "Tag_Id" contains a misprint since the table "Tags" don't have the "Cats" value.

```
Select A.Article_id, A.Article_name, U.Tag_id
From Users_Tags As U Inner Join Article_Tags As T On (U.Tag_id=T.Tag_id)
                     Inner Join Articles As A On (T.Article_id=A.Article_id)
Where U.User_id='User1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the articles that have common tags with a specific user, try this:

```
select * from articles A 
where exists(select 1 from article_tags B 
where B.article_id = A.article_id and B.tag_id IN 
(select tag_id from users_tags where user_id = 'User1'));
```